# MacBook Air with Bootcamp - How to partition?

Tags: windows-7, macos, partitioning, boot-camp

I want to buy a MacBook Air for my wife with a 128GB SSD.

She has to use Windows 7 but I would like to keep OS X for myself to use somtimes.

Using Bootcamp, is it feasible to install the following?

Mac partition: 36GB with Mac OS X and Microsoft Office 2011 Word, Excel & Powerpoint and Skype. (minimal use)

Windows partition: 92GB with Windows 7 professional and Microsoft Office 2010 Word, Excel & Powerpoint, and Skype (daily use)

Media to be kept on SD card or external USB3 drive.

(*Note: Using Parrallels may save space, but my wife won't go for the user experience*)

Comment: I do not see any problem with that.

Comment: DO you need to have data used e.g. documents  by both Windows and OSX?

Comment: No. Completely isolated is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's certainly possible. The Boot Camp assistant will allow you to select the partition size for both Windows and OS X.

If you want to be able to share files between those, it'd probably be easiest to add another small partition formatted as FAT 32 or ExFAT, which both Mac OS X and Windows can read and write to. You can do this later on – and this is entirely optional. The SD card or external drive will work just as fine.